# Guardar cadena de texto en MySQL

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql

Buenas, estoy tratando de guardar el texto que el usuario escribe en un textarea, dicho texto lo muestro posteriormente algo asi:

> Instrucciones:
>
> 1. Instruccion 1.
> 2. Instruccion 2.
> 3. Instruccion 3.

Lo que hago al momento es obligar al usuario a que agregue un caracter especifico donde quiere que termine el parrafo por lo cual lo que se almacena en la BD es algo como esto:

```
1. Instruccion 1.;2. Instruccion 2.;3. Instruccion 3.
```

Esto lo hago para despues hacer un split y mostrarlo como en la parte de arriba.

```
var split;
split = instrucciones.split(";");
```

Mi pregunta es si existe una manera de guardar el texto del textarea y que reconozca cuando el usuario da "enter" o si existe una manera de agregar un caracter especial sin necesidad que el usuario lo teclee ya que esto resulta un poco incomodo. Gracias de antemano.

PD. Estoy usando C# .ASP, JavaScript y MySQL.

Comment: pero no necesitas realizar ningun split, simplemente toma el texto del teextarea y lo persistes asi como te llega al servidor. Si depsues quieres mostrarlo en algun otro contenedor html aplciar un Replace() del "\n" por "<br>"

Comment: Es la unica manera que pense en ese momento, se guarda toda la cadena, con una consulta la obtengo y con el split separo para asignar cada cadena resultante a un "<p>" dibujado dinamicamente con ajax, la respuesta de abajo me ayudo a resolver esto pero de igual forma buscare la forma en que tu dices, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa directamente el código del "enter", cuando hagas el split usa `Split((char)13);`

Saludos,

Comment: En jQuery me marcaba error por el (char)13, lo que intente fue hacer un 'split(/\n/)' a la cadena de texto del textarea, con esto en la BD se guardaba algo asi: 1. instruccion.,2. instruccion., con una ','. Al momento de querer mostrar los valores intente de nuevo con el split pero me los muestra en un solo parrafo.

Comment: Ya quedo resuelto, tu respuesta me fue de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Donde lo presentas? nuevamente en un textarea? o en código html?  si es html debes "reparsear" cambiar todos los \n por <br/>

Comment: Hago una consulta atraves de ajax y los dibujo en un "<p>" en una funcion de javascript, pero ya quedo resuelto!